# How call data from firebase to list for line chart

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to call data from Firebase to insert into the object list but still can't call data from Firebase

and this my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNDWR.png)

this is my code for list and firebase

```
class alldataSensor {
  DateTime timeStamp;
  double sensorEc;
  double sensorPh;
  double sensorRtd;
  double humidity;
  double temperature;

  alldataSensor(
      {required this.timeStamp,
      required this.temperature,
      required this.humidity,
      required this.sensorRtd,
      required this.sensorPh,
      required this.sensorEc});


  factory alldataSensor.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return alldataSensor(
      timeStamp: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['Ts']),
      sensorEc: map['EC'] as double,
      sensorPh: map['PH'] as double,
      sensorRtd: map['RTD'] as double,
      humidity: map['humidity'] as double ,
      temperature: map['temperature'] as double,
    );
  }
}


Future<List<alldataSensor>> getallDataSensor() async {
  DatabaseReference allDataSensor = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data');
  print(allDataSensor); // to debug and see if data is returned

  List<alldataSensor> needs = [];
  allDataSensor.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =event.snapshot;
    final Map<DateTime, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value as Map<DateTime, dynamic>;
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      needs.add(value);
    });
  });
  return needs;
}
```

and this my code to call list

```
List<alldataSensor> _list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupNeeds();
  }

  _setupNeeds() async {
    List<alldataSensor> needs = await getallDataSensor();
    setState(() {
      _list = needs;
    });
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
        enablePanning: true,
        enablePinching: true,
        enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
        enableMouseWheelZooming: true,
        maximumZoomLevel: 0.5,
      ),
      plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
      primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
        intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
        dateFormat: DateFormat.yMMMd(),
        interval: 1,
        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      ),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
        axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
        majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
      ),
      legend: const Legend(
        isVisible: true,
        position: LegendPosition.bottom,
      ),
      series: <LineSeries<dynamic, DateTime>>[
        LineSeries<alldataSensor, DateTime>(
          name: 'EC',
          legendIconType: LegendIconType.circle,
          dataSource: _list,
          xValueMapper: (alldataSensor data, _) => data.timeStamp,
          yValueMapper: (alldataSensor data, _) => data.sensorEc,
          onRendererCreated: (ChartSeriesController controller) {
            seriesController = controller;
          },
        ),
        LineSeries<alldataSensor, DateTime>(
          name: 'pH',
          legendIconType: LegendIconType.circle,
          dataSource: _list,
          xValueMapper: (alldataSensor data, _) => data.timeStamp,
          yValueMapper: (alldataSensor data, _) => data.sensorPh,
          onRendererCreated: (ChartSeriesController controller) {
            seriesController = controller;
          },
        ),
      ],
      loadMoreIndicatorBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, ChartSwipeDirection direction) {
        if (direction == ChartSwipeDirection.end) {
          getallDataSensor();
          return SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.zero); // Mengganti dengan ini
        } else {
          return SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.zero);
        }
      },
    );
```

I have tried calling data from Firebase using the void, future, query data types but still can't call data from Firebase to use in the object list

I have tried calling data from Firebase using the void, future, query data types but still can't call data from Firebase to use in the object list

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from the Firebase Realtime Database (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronous, as it may take time to load. Instead of making your code (and the user) wait, the main code immediately continues to execute, and the Firebase SDK then calls a callback method that you specify when the data has been retrieved.

In your specific example this means that the `return needs` runs well before `needs.add(value)` is ever executed, so you're always returning an empty list. I recommend setting a breakpoint on each of those lines and then running in the debugger, as that is the easiest way to understand what is happening.

---

Your code will need to deal with this asynchronous behavior, which it currently fails to do. The easiest way to use a [one-time get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data_once) rather than a real-time listener, as that allows you to use `await` to wait for the data:

```
Future<List<alldataSensor>> getallDataSensor() async {
  DatabaseReference allDataSensor = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data');
  print(allDataSensor); // to debug and see if data is returned

  List<alldataSensor> needs = [];
  final snapshot = await allDataSensor.get();
  for (final dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
    final Map<DateTime, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value as Map<DateTime, dynamic>;
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      needs.add(value);
    });
  }
  return needs;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem receiving data from Firebase with 1 data type namely dynamic(int) but what is requested by line chart has 2 data types namely Datetime and dynamic